# How to access an object key in Map without iterating in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a java class **Result** and It contains a variable called **results** and it is a **HashMap**.

```
public class Result {

   private HashMap<Class1, Class2> results = new HashMap<>();

}
```

I'm using an object called **Class1** as the key for above HashMap.

```
public class Class1 {

   private String attribute1;

   private String attribute2;

   private String attribute3;

   private String attribute4;

}
```

In front end I iterated the HashMap in below way and access the values.

```
<span th:each="result : ${results}" th:if="${#strings.equals('SOME_VALUE', result.key.attribute1)}" th:text="${result.value.someAttribute}"/>
```

Using above thymeleaf code I got the expected result. But I need to know Is there any easiest way to access the HashMap values without iterating like this? I'm using **thymeleaf 3.0.0.RELEASE** version.

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the `Map` in Java or do you want to have a different iteration style in thymeleaf?

Comment: I need to know is there any way to access the results without the irteration in thymeleaf.

Comment: There are several ways to iterate over a `Map` in Java. You can iterate over the key set, make use of the `Iterator` class or just apply lambda expressions like `map.forEach`. I don't have any idea if there are alternatives in thymeleaf itself...

Comment: hashcode() and equals() methods should be implemented in Class1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [collection selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-selection) for this:

```
<span th:text="${results.^[key.attribute1 == 'SOME_VALUE'].values()[0].someAttribute}"/>
```

`results.^[key.attribute1 == 'SOME_VALUE']` returns a `HashMap` with a single element in it (it seems to me this should return a `Map.Entry`, but it doesn't). I then call [`values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values--) (a function on `HashMap` that returns the values in the HashMap as a `Collection`) and `[0]` returns the first element in that `Collection`.

Comment: This is the expected answer. thank you. please can you explain the usage of values()[0].